# Take an internal HD with Windows 10 OS and convert into a bootable external HD without re-installing Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, external-hard-drive, multi-boot, usb-boot

I will keep this as concise as possible.

My wife and I each had identical Lenovo laptops with Windows 8 preloaded and upgraded to windows 8.1. When MS offered the free upgrade to Windows 10 we took advantage.

I was then able to acquire a copy of Windows 7 and Windows 10 through school and turned my Lenovo into a dual boot system. Unfortunately, my Lenovo laptop got run over shattering the screen but the hard drive still worked. At around that time my wife purchased a new Toshiba laptop so I inherited her old Lenovo which I promptly removed her hard drive inserted mine with the dual boot system,fixed the bios to boot in legacy mode and voila was up and running for the last two years.

Yesterday for whatever reason my dual boot system became corrupted and would not boot. I have reformatted the hard drive and reinstalled Windows 7.

I have the hard drive that came out of my wife's Lenovo and it still has Windows 10 loaded on it. I know it works because when I had all the problems yesterday I swapped it out with the corrupted one and the system booted and updated without any problems.

Here is my question:

Rather than setup a dual boot system again can I set her Windows 10 hard drive up to boot externally when I want to use Windows 10? This would save me an install and update session because Windows 10 is already loaded and updated on this secondary internal drive that can be converted to an external drive.

I keep thinking it should be as simple as setting the laptop to boot to USB first and when I want to run Windows 10 plug it into the USB port prior to starting my laptop. Unfortunately, nothing is ever that easy.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you just reinstall Windows 10?  What you attempting to do is called Windows To Go, and while there are ways to create your own Windows To Go installation without using Windows 10 Enterprise there are requirements.  What might be easier is to connect both HDDs to the machine, and then simply, change the boot order when you want to boot to Windows 10.  This is far easier if both installations were installed in UEFI mode.

Comment: @Ramhound Works with windows 10 Pro too

Comment: I am trying to determine when, Windows To Go, became a feature of Windows 8.1/10 Professional, because it used to be a 8.1/10 Enterprise feature.   I also specifically recall questions asking about problems connected to Pro/Windows To Go (just can't find them).  [I hate Microsoft](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj592680(v=ws.11).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Windows To Go comes to mind.

It allows you to use an existing computer that runs windows 7 or higher, but use external storage to store your settings, so you combine both to work with your desktop. You can then move the harddrive to another windows 7, 8 or 10 computer and work on that machine too with your settings.

The internal drives on that computer won't be available though.

Windows To Go is part of Windows 8 Enterprise or Windows 10 Professional and above and can be found by going to the Control Panel (not to be mistaken with the settings app), and showing all icons.

[image]